# rid of id number in link address using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I have this link that works and leads to the correct article:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World">Article</a>
```

however I do not want the link to display the id number I want the link to look like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World">Article</a>
```

This is what I have in my .htaccess file, any help would be appreciated, thanks:

```html
Options -MultiViews
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1&linkAddress=$2 [NC,L,NE]
```

Is it poosible to remove the 21 id from the link but still use the id to get the variables from database. thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to server url `https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World` AS url `https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World` in backend? Could you please confirm this once.

Comment: I have (https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World) but I want to make it into (https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World)

Comment: You mean in browser link will be hit as `https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World` and in backend it should be served as `https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World` right? OR you are hitting `https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World` in your browser? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: yes that si what I mean, I want viewers to see https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World while in backend it serves https://www.example.com/news/21/Hello-World

Comment: I also want SEO to use https://www.example.com/news/Hello-World

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache after placing these urls in your .htaccess file. Also make sure this new rule is above your already existing `news.php` rule(shown in your samples).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(news)/(Hello-World)/?$ $1/21/$2 [NC,L]

##Placing OP's rule to serve urls starting with news with news.php in backend.
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1&linkAddress=$2 [NC,L,NE]
```

Comment: @GhaithIshaq, Happy that this has worked. On your generic ask for different articles, what is the Logic to redirect specific link to specific article? If there is no logic then we need to write this one no other go, let me know on same.

Comment: @GhaithIshaq, Yes, IMHO it will be php involved and couldn't be done in htaccess alone, we need controller for this one(though I am not an expert in it), request you to open a new question for that, since this question has an answer as per its base scope(Moreover to make rule generic `Hello-World` could be replaced with `[\w-]+` but still id part should be handled by controller of language only), you are always welcome to open new question with your efforts in forums, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: k i will try research and try a bit on my own then i will open a new question